# How to check success or error in json response in php function

Tags: php, json

Json response returns

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2015 09:24:20 GMT {"success":true}`
```

or

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json 
Date: Mon, 20 Jul 2015 09:24:20 GMT {"error":"Trying to get property of non-object"}
```

How to write php code to check wether there is success or error.

Doing it like this

```
$abc=$this->store($values,$reallocation_type,'multiple');

                    if(strpos($abc,'success') !== false)
                    {
                        echo "YES";
                    }
```

Comment: Please provide at least your attempt...

Comment: @teoreda added code, but i am not sure this is right way.

Comment: I guess that no code was why you got downvoted. Since you have added code, I have upvoted you. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
$response = @json_decode($abc);
if ($response && true === $response->success) {
    // success
} else {
    //failure
}
```

Comment: I would throw some more brackets in there, unless you are certain that `===` has higher precedence than `&&`. Even then, I would throw some more brackets in anyway: brackets are like pizzas - you can never have too many ;-)   `if (($response) && (true === $response->success))`

Comment: Parenthesis will not add anything to this as for to have this expression evaluate to true, both statements must be truthy and we are not mixing operators.

Comment: It returns $response null

Comment: @Piyush then the code you provided is misleading. Define your problem more clearly.

Comment: @MatissTreinis   the point of the brackets is to show which the "both statements" are.  Without brackets, if I am not 100% certain of the order of precedence, they could be either `if (($response) && (true === $response->success))` or `if (($response && true) === $response->success)`. Order of precedence tends to be error prone. In my opinion, lack of such brackets is a code smell. And adding them certainly can't hurt. As always, just IMO and YMMV :-)

Comment: @Mawg adding completely useless constructs to the code just because you don't know how the logical operators work is even bigger code smell. Not to mention that your example has no basis in real life, as if it would, about 99% of the code would be horribly broken. Please, refer yourself to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity

Comment: Sigh, well, let' agree to differ. Bracketing has been a coding standard at most for the companies where I have worked these last few decades. Not everyone has the complete table of operator precedence in their heads; errors frequently **do** occur there. Where added brackets make the code more or less legible is a matter of opinion, I guess. For me, they are definitely a good idea as I switch languages often.  Ok, let' agree to differ.

Comment: @Mawg rule of thumb you can fallow to ease your life is, if the expression has logical operators of the same type exclusively, you should not use parenthesis. If there is at least one different operator - use of parenthesis is encouraged. 

Don't get me wrong, I am all for explicit grouping, but only when that makes sense.

Comment: Nice rule (so long as you remember the groups ;-)  Yes, I see the the non-existent operator in `if ($response` is really `if ($response != NULL` and `!=` and `===`are in the same group, so I get your point, which is a good one.  I do think, though, that I have had trouble in C with the `&&` operator (maybe something like `if (a || b && c || d)`)   Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Mawg I was actually talking about logical operators like AND, OR, etc, not comparison operators like (!=, ==, etc). As long as you have only "&&" or only "||" you can do just fine without parenthesis. In your last sample there is a need for explicit parenthesis, eg `( (a || b) && (c || d) )`

As for the $response, it is evaluated as "if $response is truthy", e.g. true, not null, not empty or otherwise according to PHP casting table